# Safe publication of immutable objects in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, java.util.concurrent

I want to understand if `volatile` is needed to publish immutable objects.

For example, assuming we have an immutable object `A`:

```
// class A is immutable
class A {
  final int field1;
  final int field2;

  public A(int f1, int f2) {
    field1 = f1;
    field2 = f2;
  }
}
```

Then we have a class `B` that is accessed from different threads. It holds a reference to an object of class `A`:

```
// class B publishes object of class A through a public filed
class B {
  private /* volatile? */ A toShare;

  // this getter might be called from different threads
  public A getA(){
    return toShare;
  }

  // this might be called from different threads
  public void setA(num1, num2) {
    toShare = new A(num1, num2);
  }
}
```

From my reading it seems immutable objects can be safely published through **any means**, so does that mean we don't need to declare `toShare` as `volatile` to ensure its memory visibility?

Comment: If any thread is able to retrieve a reference to the `A` object through `toShare`, that `A` object is guaranteed to be fully initialized.

Comment: But would that retrieved `A` be the most up-to-date value? Because other threads might update `toShare` through the `setA` method. Does JVM guarantee the value updated won't be cached locally in the setting thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not guaranteed that you'll be seeing all updates to the `toShare` field of your shared data. This is because your shared data does not use any synchronization constructs that guarantee its visibility or the visibility of references reachable through it across threads. This makes it open game for numerous optimizations on the compiler and hardware level.

You can safely change your `toShare` field to reference a `String` (which is also immutable for all your purposes) and you'll probably (and correctly) feel more uneasy about its update visibility.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/xQuJCAdv) you can see a rudimentary example I've created that can show how updates are lost without any additional measures to publish changes to the reference of an immutable object. I've ran it using the `-server` JVM flag on JDK 8u65 and Intel® Core™ i5-2557M, disregarding the possibly thrown `NullPointerException` and saw the following results:

- Without `safe` being `volatile`, the second thread doesn't terminate because it doesn't see many of the changes made by the first thread

*Console output:*

```
[T1] Shared data visible here is 2147483647
```

- When `safe` is changed to be `volatile`, the second thread terminates alongside the first thread

*Console output:*

```
[T1] Shared data visible here is 2147483647
[T2] Last read value here is 2147483646
[T2] Shared data visible here is 2147483647
```

P.S. And a question to you - what happens if `sharedData` (and not `safe`) is made `volatile`? What could happen according to the JMM?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! For making `sharedData` volatile, my initial guess would be that the second thread would never terminate. The logic is that marking `sharedData` `volatile` would make the thread reading `sharedData` sync to the memory view of the thread last wrote to it. But in this example it is only written once during construction. Since thread 1 never wrote to `sharedData`, thread 2 would never sync with thread 1's memory view. However, when I tried it out, thread 2 does terminate properly. Can you elaborate on the reasoning behind it? thanks a lot!

Comment: Do not put code that is integral to your answer on an external site.  Include it your answer.

Comment: @VGR I'd argue that the code is an illustration that is not an integral part of my answer. I've put it mainly to show that in many cases (when you need to have existential quantification or to refute universal quantification), a quick test can be enough. I still would have included the code if I didn't think that it will make the whole text harder to read. So while I agree with you in general, I'll pass on your suggestion.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov if `toShare` variable is declared as `volatile`, `A` class doesn't even has to be defined as immutable, unless its state cant be modified after the construction. AFAIK when assigning a reference to a variable declared as a `volatile` all writes prior to assignment must `happen-before`. Which means that object of `A` class will already be properly constructed at the time of assignement. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is **NO**, it is needed to use `volatile` or any other way (for example, add `synchronized` keyword to both signatures get and set) to make a Happens/Before edge. Final fields semantic only guarantees that if someone sees a pointer to an instance of the class, all final fields have their values set according to constructor when it is finished:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5

And this says nothing about visibility of the reference itself. Since your example uses non-final field

> private A toShare;

you have to take care about visibility of the field with `volatile` or `synchronized` section or a java.util.concurrent.locks.Locks or AtomicReference etc. to initiate/guarantee cache synchronization. Some useful stuff, BTW, about finals and safe publication  http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/

http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/all-fields-are-final/

Comment: I think `Final fields semantic only guarantees that if someone sees a pointer to an instance of the class, all final fields have their values set according to constructor by the moment` only applies if object is properly constructed. I.e won't leak a reference to `this` within a constructor.

Comment: yes - "set according to constructor when it is _finished_"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like JMM should take care of the visibility problem for publishing immutable objects, at least that what's said in Concurrency in Practice, **3.5.2 Immutable Objects and Initialization Safely**:

> Because immutable objects are so important, the JavaMemory Model offers a special guarantee of initialization safety 
>   for sharing immutable objects. As we've seen, that an object reference becomes visible to another thread does not 
>   necessarily mean that the state of that object is visible to the consuming thread. In order to guarantee a consistent view 
>   of the object's state, synchronization is needed.
>
> Immutable objects, on the other hand, can be safely accessed even when synchronization is not used to publish the 
>   object reference. For this guarantee of initialization safety to hold, all of the requirements for immutability must be met: 
>   unmodifiable state, all fields are final, and proper construction.
>
> Immutable objects can be used safely by any thread without additional synchronization, even when synchronization is 
>   not used to publish them.

The following chapter **3.5.3 Safe publication Idioms** states that safe publication is required only **for non-immutable objects** using the following approaches:

1. Static initializer
2. Storing reference in volatile/final/AtomicReference
3. Storing reference that is guarded by the lock

Comment: I think you are wrong here because Chapter 3.4.2 from the same book is called "Example: Using volatile to publish immutable objects" where it states the following "This combination of an immutable holder object for multiple state variables related by an invariant, and a volatile reference used to ensure its timely visibility, allows VolatileCachedFactorizer to be thread-safe". Which means you still need to use volatile to ensure immutable object is visible to other threads.